# How to refresh the RadGrid control using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radgrid

This function gives error:

```
function RefreshGrid(){
    window.location.href="Form_ElameMamoreBazdid.aspx";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Java Script **

```
function refreshGrid() {                   
    $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest();                  
}
```

** C# **

```
protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{        
        Shomare_Darkhast = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["Shomare_Darkhast"]);
        Grid_Bazdid.DataSource = Ent.ShowBazdid(Shomare_Darkhast);
        Grid_Bazdid.DataBind();

}
public ObjectQuery ShowBazdid(decimal Shomare_Darkhast)
{
   var List = from b in TBL_Bazdid
               where (b.Shomare_Darkhast == Shomare_Darkhast)
               join k in TBL_Karshenas on b.Code_Karshenas equals k.Code_Karshenas
               select new
               {
                   Radif = b.Radif,
                   Code_Karshenas = b.Code_Karshenas,
                   NameNameKhanevadegie_Karshenas = k.NameNameKhanevadegie_Karshenas,
                   Tarikh = b.Tarikh,
                   SaateShoro = b.SaateShoro,
               };
    return (ObjectQuery)List;
}
```

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid

Answer (score 0):

```
function RefreshGrid()
{
  var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
  masterTable.rebind();
}
```

Please take a look at above code.

By using client binding for the grid [check out this help document](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-client-side-binding-specifics.html)!

Comment: **Microsoft JScript runtime error**: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: There was a problem extracting DataKeyValues from the DataSource. Please ensure that DataKeyNames are specified correctly and all fields specified exist in the DataSource.

Comment: For that you must have to use advance data binding for radgrid, please check below link for this.http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/needdatasource/defaultcs.aspx

You this get error because you assigned datakeynames in mastertableview/DetailTable which was not in assigned data source.

Comment: **There is another way to refresh؟**